# Azure Functions - files create location

Tags: azure, openssl, azure-functions

I've written a C# .NET6 azure function by http trigger themeplate, and tested in local, which successfully use OpenSSL to generate a privateKeyFile.key, and a csrFile.csr. Running the function in local it works perfectly, and I find both generated file in projectFolder>bin>debug path.

When I deploy my function in Azure (Linux environment) and test it the same way, an OpenSSL error occurs: Can't open "privateKeyFile.key" for writing, Permission denied\n\n".

So, I have two question:

- Is there a way to grant writing permission in order to complete the operation?
- Where I should find the file created?

My function code (I don't think that read it could help understanding the problem, anyway I leave it here)

```
     using System;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
     using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
     using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
     using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
     using Newtonsoft.Json;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Diagnostics;
        
        
     namespace CertificateManager
     {
         public static class Function1
         {
        
             [FunctionName("Function1")]
             public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
                 [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
                 ILogger log)
             {
                 log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        
                 var response = new CsrResponse();
        
                 var originalName = req.Query["Organization"];
                 var name = originalName.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
                 var keyFileName = $"{name}.key";
                 var csrFileName = $"{name}.csr";
        
                 DeleteFileIfExists(keyFileName);
                 DeleteFileIfExists(csrFileName);
        
                 var subject = $"/C={req.Query["Country"]}/ST={req.Query["State"]}/L={req.Query["Location"]}/O={req.Query["Organization"]}/OU={req.Query["OrganizationalUnit"]}/CN={req.Query["CommonName"]}";
                 var command = $" req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout \"{keyFileName}\" -out \"{csrFileName}\" -subj \"{subject}\"";
        
                 var logs = ExecuteOpenSsl(command);
                 response.Logs = logs.ToString();
        
                 if (File.Exists(csrFileName))
                 {
                     var text = new StringBuilder();
                     text.AppendLine(await File.ReadAllTextAsync(csrFileName));
                     text.AppendLine(await File.ReadAllTextAsync(keyFileName));
        
                     response.CsrText = text.ToString();
                 }
                 log.LogInformation(response.ToString());
                 return new OkObjectResult(response);
             } 
        
             private static StringBuilder ExecuteOpenSsl(string command)
             {
                 var logs = new StringBuilder();
                 var executableName = "openssl";
                 var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executableName)
                 {
                     Arguments = command,
                     UseShellExecute = false,
                     RedirectStandardError = true,
                     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                     CreateNoWindow = true
                 };
        
                 var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
                 while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                 {
                     logs.AppendLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                 }
                 logs.AppendLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
                 return logs;
             }
        
             private static void DeleteFileIfExists(string keyFileName)
             {
                 if (System.IO.File.Exists(keyFileName))
                 {
                     System.IO.File.Delete(keyFileName);
                 }
             }
        
             // models
             public class CsrResponse
             {
                 public string CsrText { get; set; }
                 public string Logs { get; set; }
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @*Ketan* for the workaround posting your [***suggestion***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768096/unable-to-create-file-in-azure-functions) in community wiki to help other community members for the similar issue so that they can find fix their problem.

> *With the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting value of 1, the zip deployment APIs copy your package to the d:\home\data\SitePackages
> folder instead of extracting the files to d:\home\site\wwwroot. It
> also creates the packagename.txt file. After a restart, the package is
> mounted to wwwroot as a read-only filesystem. Run From Package makes
> wwwroot read-only, so you will receive an error when writing files to
> this directory.*

- And also make sure that you have added the `connection string` in your configuration in azure as `localsettings.json` not upload to cloud automatically.

For more information please refer this **SO THREAD**| [***Azure function write to file***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69293403/azure-function-write-to-file)